# execute proc that returns varying columns in linq to sql

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have a stored proc.
It returns varying columns for each shop.

For ex:
(i) shop has 5 metrics, then it will return data related to those 5.

(ii) if shop has 10 - it will return 10.

The results are from the dynamic sql query return in the proc.

How can we execute this proc in linq to sql?
Linq is expecting to define columns in .dbml before hand and I do not know my columns until I execute the proc.

Can somebody advise if it is possible in linq to sql???

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends.

Do you know if there is a hard upper limit on the number of columns?

If so, then you could "brute" it by making a class with properties representing `Column1`...`ColumnN` whereby the constructor sets all properties to null and then if you want these results auto-mapped then you could use [DataContext.ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx) where T=that class you just created;

BUT that will really only work if there is a known upper limit. Otherwise you can't just dynamically map an unknown number of columns automatically using Linq2Sql; bear in mind that when you map a table or stored procedure in Linq2Sql all that's happening is that a class in a .cs file is being generated for you with a set number of properties that doesn't change at runtime.

In this case, you're probably better off using `System.Data.DataTable` or similar for this and/or write your own DataTable->Object mapper if you really want to use objects.

Another thing to consider, if you control the SQL that retrieves these results, is if you can pivot the query - return multiple *rows* instead of columns, with the receiving class having 2 properties, one for the "Column" name and another for the row value; this will work just fine with `DataContext.ExecuteQuery`